# Downloading a file from internet to ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

For a web application I'm currently working on, I want to download a file from internet to my web server. 
I can use below code to download the file to the web server's hard drive, what should I set to the destination path to get this working. We are planing to host this site in a shared hosting environment.

```
using System.Net;

using(var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://file.com/file.txt", @"C:\file.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think common way to do it is this:

```
string appdataFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();
```

or

```
string appdataFolder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data");
```

Also notice, that WebClient class implements IDisposable, so you should use dispose or using struct.
And I eager you to read some naming convention for c# (local variables usually start with lower case letter).

Comment: corrected the pointed mistakes, both in question and in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload it from your machine to server through ftp request,

```
string _remoteHost = "ftp://ftp.site.com/htdocs/directory/";
    string _remoteUser = "site.com";
    string _remotePass = "password";
    string sourcePath = @"C:\";

    public void uploadFile(string name)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_remoteHost +name+ ".txt");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_remoteUser, _remotePass);


        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(sourcePath + name+ ".txt");
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        response.Close();
    }
```